# springdoc-openapi-ui does not read provided yaml configuration

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to migrate app from autogenerating openapi from existing controllers and model to yaml specification(from which controller interfaces/models will be generated). YAML file is ready, bean OpenAPI providing some information is gone,  I set `springdoc.packages-to-scan=` and tried to point to yaml file using:
`springdoc.api-docs.path=/api.yaml` and/or `springdoc.swagger-ui.url=http://localhost:8080/ofs/api.yaml`, but for some reason, while I get updated URL for 'source' yaml file, it is *not* the source file, it was somehow autogenerated. I see wrong servers, some default title etc.

sole maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I didn't find any autoconfiguration. I think I see results of some "we will do magic for you" default configuration, but I cannot find anywhere (tutorials/documentation) how to force system to: "don't do anything, use this configuration".

Can someone advice / point me to documentation(specific section) or some tutorial? Or did I get it wrong and in this case I should not use springdoc-openapi-ui at all?